# How to create spring boot batch project without spring batch metadata?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-batch

I want to use spring boot batch project without metadata,
Previously my existing project had done that with the help of MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean but as it is deprecated in v2.4.0 now I can not able to upgrade it to current latest v2.7.0.

my old code is as below:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MetaDataConfiguration {

  private final ApiConfiguration apiConfiguration;

  @Bean
  DefaultBatchConfigurer batchConfigurer() {
    return new DefaultBatchConfigurer() {
      private final JobRepository jobRepository;
      private final JobExplorer jobExplorer;
      private final JobLauncher jobLauncher;

      {
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactory = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        try {
          this.jobRepository = jobRepositoryFactory.getObject();
          MapJobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorerFactory = new MapJobExplorerFactoryBean(
              jobRepositoryFactory);
          this.jobExplorer = jobExplorerFactory.getObject();
          SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
          assert jobRepository != null;
          jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
          jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
          this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
        } catch (Exception e) {
          throw new BatchConfigurationException(e);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public JobRepository getJobRepository() {
        return jobRepository;
      }

      @Override
      public JobExplorer getJobExplorer() {
        return jobExplorer;
      }

      @Override
      public JobLauncher getJobLauncher() {
        return jobLauncher;
      }
    };
  }
.
.
.
```

I have tried diff solutions available and also asked several questions in stackoverflow but not worked,
Please share alternative solution code of it.

Comment: You always have metadata, however you throw it away afterwards. Use H2 with an in-memory database insead of the `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean`, also if something is deprecated it doesn't mean it doesn't work anymore, it will be removed in some future version (which in this case is Spring Batch 5, which is for Spring Boot 3).

Comment: @M.Deinum I am trying to set H2 for metadata but can not able to implement it with regular mysql database, 
Could you please share example code/reference code for this?

Comment: Your config should still work and will break with newer Spring Boot versions (althouhg you will get a warning). What have you tried so far?

Comment: As of now I had tried to setup EmbeddedDatabase with H2.
My config will work now but at last I need to replace it with some other solution in future, that's why I am looking for alternative solution of it.

Comment: I still have no clue on what you did, and from the looks of it you simply try to hard to work around the standard configuration. What you need, or should, is an H2 datasource and annotate it with `@BatchDataSource` so it will be used by Spring Batch for metadata. You can then (and should) ditch this `batchConfigurer` bean.

Answer (score 0):

I worked in a project that was using MongoDB and I did not have a relation data base. And the best tool to work on that situation was Spring Batch.
In fact, I created more than one project running like that and I have no memory issues with this. I have one project on Github with this implemented, take a look about dependencies or another possible questions. [Link](https://github.com/gbvbahia01/Spring-Batch-Thread-ItemReader-Stuck) (This project is about another topic, BUT uses the memory cleaning strategy which I am referring to)

I use H2, in memory data base. And to avoid memory issues I clean the memory every 1 minute. I created this:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@Profile("!test")
public class H2CleanerScheduler {

  private final H2CleanerRepository h2CleanerRepository;
  
  @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${app.h2.scheduler.clean}")
  public void callH2Cleaner() {
    log.trace("Init Job memory cleaner");
    h2CleanerRepository.cleanMemoryCompletedJobs();
    log.trace("End Job memory cleaner");
  }
}
```

And this:

```
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class H2CleanerRepository {

  private static final String SELECT_JOB_INSTANCE_ID =
      "SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE STATUS = 'COMPLETED'";
  private static final String SELECT_JOB_EXECUTION_ID =
      "SELECT JOB_EXECUTION_ID FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_INSTANCE_ID IN (:selectJobInstanceCompleted)";
  private static final String SELECT_STEP_EXECUTION_ID =
      "SELECT STEP_EXECUTION_ID FROM BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID IN (:selectJobExecutionIdFromCompleted)";

  private static final String DELETE_BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT =
      "DELETE FROM BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID IN ( :stepIds )";
  private static final String DELETE_BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION =
      "DELETE FROM BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION WHERE STEP_EXECUTION_ID IN ( :stepIds )";
  private static final String DELETE_BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT =
      "DELETE FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID IN ( :jobExecIds )";
  private static final String DELETE_BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS =
      "DELETE FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID IN ( :jobExecIds )";
  private static final String DELETE_BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION =
      "DELETE FROM BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION where JOB_EXECUTION_ID IN  ( :jobExecIds )";
  private static final String DELETE_BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE =
      "DELETE FROM BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE WHERE JOB_INSTANCE_ID IN ( :jobInstanceIds )";

  private final DataSource dataSource;


  public void cleanMemoryCompletedJobs() {
    try {

      NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);

      List<Long> jobInstanceCompletedIds = findAllIDsJobCompleted(template);

      if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(jobInstanceCompletedIds)) {
        return;
      }

      List<Long> jobJobExecutionIdFromCompletedIds =
          findAllIDsJobExecutionCompleted(template, jobInstanceCompletedIds);

      if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(jobJobExecutionIdFromCompletedIds)) {
        return;
      }

      List<Long> stepExecutionIdFromJobExecutionId =
          findAllIDsStepExecutionCompleted(template, jobJobExecutionIdFromCompletedIds);

      if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(stepExecutionIdFromJobExecutionId)) {
        return;
      }

      deleteByIDsCompleted(template, jobInstanceCompletedIds, jobJobExecutionIdFromCompletedIds,
          stepExecutionIdFromJobExecutionId);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error(String.format("Error on clean H2 Memory: %s", e.getMessage()), e);
    }
  }

  private List<Long> findAllIDsJobCompleted(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template) {
    
    List<Long> jobInstanceCompletedIds =
        template.query(SELECT_JOB_INSTANCE_ID, (rs, rowNum) -> {
            return rs.getLong(1);
        });
    
    return jobInstanceCompletedIds;
  }
  
  private List<Long> findAllIDsJobExecutionCompleted(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template,
      List<Long> jobInstanceCompletedIds) {
    
    MapSqlParameterSource jobInstanceCompletedIdsParam = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    jobInstanceCompletedIdsParam.addValue("selectJobInstanceCompleted", jobInstanceCompletedIds);

    List<Long> jobJobExecutionIdFromCompletedIds = template.query(SELECT_JOB_EXECUTION_ID,
        jobInstanceCompletedIdsParam, new RowMapper<Long>() {
          @Override
          public Long mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            return rs.getLong(1);
          }
        });
    
    return jobJobExecutionIdFromCompletedIds;
  }

  private List<Long> findAllIDsStepExecutionCompleted(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template,
      List<Long> jobJobExecutionIdFromCompletedIds) {
    
    MapSqlParameterSource jobExecutionIdFromCompletedIdsParam = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    jobExecutionIdFromCompletedIdsParam.addValue("selectJobExecutionIdFromCompleted",
        jobJobExecutionIdFromCompletedIds);

    List<Long> stepExecutionIdFromJobExecutionId = template.query(SELECT_STEP_EXECUTION_ID,
        jobExecutionIdFromCompletedIdsParam, (rs, rowNum) -> {
            return rs.getLong(1);
        });
    
    return stepExecutionIdFromJobExecutionId;
  }

  private void deleteByIDsCompleted(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template,
      List<Long> jobInstanceCompletedIds, List<Long> jobJobExecutionIdFromCompletedIds,
      List<Long> stepExecutionIdFromJobExecutionId) {
    MapSqlParameterSource stepIdsParam = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    stepIdsParam.addValue("stepIds", stepExecutionIdFromJobExecutionId);

    MapSqlParameterSource jobExecIdsParam = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    jobExecIdsParam.addValue("jobExecIds", jobJobExecutionIdFromCompletedIds);

    MapSqlParameterSource jobInstanceIdsParam = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    jobInstanceIdsParam.addValue("jobInstanceIds", jobInstanceCompletedIds);

    template.update(DELETE_BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT, stepIdsParam);
    template.update(DELETE_BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION, stepIdsParam);
    template.update(DELETE_BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT, jobExecIdsParam);
    template.update(DELETE_BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS, jobExecIdsParam);
    template.update(DELETE_BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION, jobExecIdsParam);
    template.update(DELETE_BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE, jobInstanceIdsParam);
  }
  
}
```